# Thread safety with Java static inner class field

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class something like this:

```
public class Outer {

    public static final TaskUpdater TASK_UPDATER = new TaskUpdater() {

        public void doSomething(Task task) {
            //uses and modifies task and some other logic
        }
    };

    public void taskRelatedMethod() {
        //some logic
        TASK_UPDATER.doSomething(new Task());
        //some other logic
    }
}
```

I've noticed some strange behaviour when running this in a multi-threaded environment that I can't reproduce locally, and I suspect it's a threading issue. Is it possible for two instances of Outer to somehow interfere with each other by both calling doSomething on TASK_UPDATER? Each will be passing a difference instance of Task into the doSomething method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the strange behavior you observed?

Comment: Given that `doSomething()` is not synchronized, of course, two threads can execute `doSomething()` concurrently. Can it cause "interferences"? How could we tell without seeing a single line of code of this class?

Comment: Each thread is working on it's own instance of `Task`?  Are there any fields in `Outer` that are modified?

Comment: The example is contrived to simplify a much more complex example. I guess what I was getting at is whether it is possible for two threads to both run doSomething() and interfere with each other. Given that the instances of Task are different and that no fields in Outer are modified, is any sort of interference possible? Surely each execution of the method would be independent, at least in terms of local variables.

Comment: In terms of local variables, yes. But in terms of instance variables of the shared TaskUpdater object, no. Shared state is what you have to worry about in concurrent programming.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for two instances of Outer to somehow interfere with each other by both calling doSomething on TASK_UPDATER?

The answer is "it depends".  Any time you have multiple threads sharing the same object instances, you may have concurrency issues.  In your case, you have multiple instances of `Outer` sharing the same `static` `TaskUpdater` instance.  This in itself is not a problem however if `TaskUpdater` has any fields, they will be shared by the threads.  If the threads make any changes to those fields in any way then data synchronization needs to happen and possible blocking around critical code sections.  If the `TaskUpdater` is *only* reading and operating on the `Task` argument, which seems to be per `Outer` instance, then there is no problem.

For example, you could have a task updater like:

```
public static final TaskUpdater TASK_UPDATER = new TaskUpdater() {
    public void doSomething(Task task) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Job job : task.getJobs() {
            total += job.getSize();
        }
        task.setTotalSize(total);
    }
};
```

In this case, the task is only changing the `Task` instance passed in.  It can use local variables without a problem because those are on the stack and now shared between threads.  This is thread safe.

However consider this updater:

```
public static final TaskUpdater TASK_UPDATER = new TaskUpdater() {
    private long total = 0;
    public void doSomething(Task task) {
        for (Job job : task.getJobs() {
            // race condition and memory synchronization issues here
            total += job.getSize();
        }
    }
    public long getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
};
```

In this case, both threads will be updating the same `total` field on the shard `TaskUpdater`.  This is not thread safe since you have race conditions around the `+=` (since it is 3 operations: get, plus, set) as well as memory synchronization issues.  One thread may have a cached version of `total` which is 5 which it increments to 6 but another thread has already incremented its cached version of `total` to 10.

When threads *share* common fields you need to protect those operations and worry about synchronization in terms of mutex access and memory publishing.  In this case, making `total` be an `AtomicLong` will be in order.

```
    private AtomicLong total = new AtomicLong(0);
      ...
            total.addAndGet(job.getSize());
```

`AtomicLong` wraps a `volatile long` so the memory is published appropriately to all threads and it has code that does atomic test/set operations which removes the race conditions.